# Javafx Gridpane layout being really weird

Tags: java, javafx

I tried to just make a simple Gridpane that would ask the user to input two numbers. For some reason the elements just went all over the place. I'm pretty sure I got the constraints correct.

This is my Settings class.

```
public class Settings {
    
    public static void display() {
        GridPane layout = new GridPane();
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        layout.setVgap(8);
        layout.setHgap(10);
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 600, 400);
        
        //Title label
        Label label = new Label("Settings");
        GridPane.setConstraints(label, 1, 0);
        
        //Minutes label
        Label minutesLabel = new Label("Minutes:");
        GridPane.setConstraints(minutesLabel, 0, 1);
        
        //Minutes input
        TextField minutesInput = new TextField();
        minutesInput.setPromptText("minutes");
        GridPane.setConstraints(minutesInput, 1, 1);
        
        //Seconds label
        Label secondsLabel = new Label("Seconds:");
        GridPane.setConstraints(secondsLabel, 0, 2);
        
        //Seconds input
        TextField secondsInput = new TextField();
        secondsInput.setPromptText("seconds");
        GridPane.setConstraints(secondsInput, 1, 2);
        
        //Ok button
        Button okButton = new Button("Ok");
        okButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            try {
                int minutes = Integer.parseInt(minutesInput.getText());
                int seconds = Integer.parseInt(secondsInput.getText());
                if(minutes > 59) minutes = 59;
                else if(minutes < 1) minutes = 1;
                if(seconds > 59) seconds = 59;
                else if(seconds < 1) seconds = 1;
                Main.updateMinsAndSecs(minutes, seconds);
                Main.setSceneMain();
            }catch(NumberFormatException numberFormatException) {
                label.setText("Please enter valid number(s)");
            }catch(FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) {
                fileNotFoundException.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        okButton.setStyle("-fx-background-radius: 0;");
        GridPane.setConstraints(secondsInput, 0, 3);
        
        //Cancel button
        Button cancelButton = new Button("Cancel");
        cancelButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            Main.setSceneMain();
        });
        cancelButton.setStyle("-fx-background-radius: 0;");
        GridPane.setConstraints(secondsInput, 1, 3);
        
        //Apply button
        Button applyButton = new Button("Apply");
        applyButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            try {
                int minutes = Integer.parseInt(minutesInput.getText());
                int seconds = Integer.parseInt(secondsInput.getText());
                if(minutes > 59) minutes = 59;
                else if(minutes < 1) minutes = 1;
                if(seconds > 59) seconds = 59;
                else if(seconds < 1) seconds = 1;
                Main.updateMinsAndSecs(minutes, seconds);
            }catch(NumberFormatException numberFormatException) {
                label.setText("Please enter valid number(s)");
            }catch(FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) {
                fileNotFoundException.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        applyButton.setStyle("-fx-background-radius: 0;");
        GridPane.setConstraints(secondsInput, 2, 3);
    
        layout.getChildren().addAll(label, minutesLabel, minutesInput, secondsLabel, secondsInput, okButton, cancelButton, applyButton);
    
        Main.window.setScene(scene);
        Main.window.setTitle("Settings");
    }
}
```

This is how it turned out.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3cui.png)

I would like the solution to not use fxml.

Stackoverflow says my post is mostly code and I need more details so I'm also going to say that I have used a Gridpane to create a simple login screen and that one was pretty good. The code was basically the same except the positioning and the content.

Comment: You have copy-and-paste errors in your last two calls to `GridPane.setConstraints(...)`, where you are resetting the constraints for `secondsInput`, instead of setting the constraints for `cancelButton` and `applyButton`

Comment: Some advice:  use [addRow](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#addRow(int,javafx.scene.Node...)).  Specifically, something like `layout.add(row++, label, field);` will reduce the likelihood of errors.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are setting different constraints to `secondsInput` instead of `okButton`, `cancelButton` and `applyButton`:

```
    GridPane.setConstraints(secondsInput, 1, 2);
    GridPane.setConstraints(secondsInput, 0, 3);
    GridPane.setConstraints(secondsInput, 1, 3);
    GridPane.setConstraints(secondsInput, 2, 3);
```

Instead of:

```
    GridPane.setConstraints(secondsInput, 1, 2);
    GridPane.setConstraints(okButton, 0, 3);
    GridPane.setConstraints(cancelButton, 1, 3);
    GridPane.setConstraints(applyButton, 2, 3);
```

Comment: not mine (would tell you, as you know :) - but I understand it: IMO you shouldn't have answered at all because it's a simple c&p error, that was hinted at in the comments already. While they happen all the time having them asked/answered again and again for individual variations doesn't help anybody in future. The question should be closed to make that absolutely clear.

Comment: Understood, and makes sense ;) - didn't see the comment.